# HeightForRowAt and estimatedHeightForRowAt in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 2 tableview in one ViewController. Cell height of both tableview is different.

In first tableview am calculating via **`heightForRowAt`** delegate method because in that table content of a cell is static. In second via **`estimatedHeightForRowAt`** delegate method because in that table content of a cell is text(that may be small or large).

So the problem is the cell height second tableview fixed 58. That is not increasing while large text display.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if tableView == tblHistory{
        let h = ((tableView.frame.size.width - 16) * 7 / 5) + 74
        return h
    }
    else{
        return 58
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if tableView == tblHistory{
        let h = ((tableView.frame.size.width - 16) * 7 / 5) + 74
        return h
    }
    else{
        return 58
    }
}
```

**Notes**: I have properly set all constraints to resize cell height depends on text.

Comment: try to return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` instead of `0`

Comment: If your constraints are set properly, then you don't need to calculate the height. Just return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for both the table views.

Comment: @hardikparmar you are right.

Answer (score 2):

> the problem is the height of text cell fixed. That is not increasing while large text display.

You really have to have perfection in your **constraints** within the cell on the storyboard.

There is really a lot to know.  You would have to show (screenshot) the storyboard of the cell, and show all the vertical constraints linking the `UILabel` and the other items.

Generally speaking you should not be "fixing" the height of the UILabel, or the overall "chain" that includes the UILabel.   If you do that correctly, it's implicit height will work.

Comment: Let me put a tip here: When creating cells with automatic dimensions in storyboard you should first put a "panel" view on the cell which should contain all your other views. This panel should have leading, trailing, top and bottom constraint put to superview at 0 but the bottom constraint priority should be set to 100. Your cell will never resize in your storyboard but now you can see your panel resizing correctly when you modify any parameters so you can debug your autosizing.

Comment: Exactly, that is one definite approach to learning the "art of autolayout".

Comment: personally i recommend "stack view everywhere"  :)

Answer (score 1):

If your constraints are set properly, then you don't need to calculate the height. Just return `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for both the table views.

Comment: Problems were not in second tableview constrains I have set all constraints perfectly and that was work perfectly also. Problem in first tableview. That is i was calculating height programmatically instaded of constraints.

Comment: Then you should show a screenshot of storyboard with the constraints so we can correct it.

Answer (score -1):

Best solution is calculating height for both texts with the same method in **heightForRowAt**:

```
func heightForText(string: String, width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
    let attrString = NSAttributedString(
        string: string,
        attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font])
    let size = attrString.boundingRect(
    with: CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), 
    options: NSStringDrawingOptions.usesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil)
    return size.height
}
```

Comment: however, this is usually not a good approach -  you should be using autolayout and constraints.

Comment: Please explain why 'this is usually not a good approach'. My solution doesn't excluding autolayout.

Comment: hi Konrad , my point was: there is no reason to find the height of that element.  (Indeed, there is no reason to find the height of any element.)  Use autolayout alone and it will size everything.

Comment: If you are using autolayout in tableView (I mean 'UITableViewAutomaticDimension' for rowHeight) it will smash your performance for more complex layout. That's why I think that better solution is calculating height for entire cell and return it in heightForRowAt. I didn't say that this is the only one solution.

Comment: i have already mention i am using constraints in app. then why i should have to write hard code. I was trying via hard code that was my mistake.

Comment: I you want only only resolve the problem easiest way ok... But it's not complicated and you can gain more than lose

Comment: hi @KonradPiękoś, I'm afraid I don't agree, with modern iOS, dynamic height with recycling cells is very fast.  it "used to be" that realistically you had to calculate it manually, but not now.   It's possible we are talking about slightly different situations, but nowadays for infinite (huge) dynamic cells, we use autolayout.

Comment: There is dozen articles about smooth scrolling. E.g.
https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/perfect-smooth-scrolling-in-uitableviews-fd609d5275a5

Comment: Just create a simple chat (with the dynamic length of the texts) scrolling from bottom to top, run it on older iPad and see what happens. It will not work smoothly... And if you add to this also images in cells?